# I need to scale one end of a model

Tags: scale

I have created a fairly complex model and now realise that I have made an error in one aspect of the dimensions. Rather than redo the entire model I can imagine a fix but I'm not sure if this is even possible.

My imagined solution relies on fixing the complex model in some kind of 3D rectangular bounding box and then scaling one face of the box in the Z dimension such that the bounding box becomes more of a trapezoidal shape.

My hopes increased when I read about the scale cage tool but this scales all faces by the same amount

[image: Before]
[image: After]

If you can imagine my model fitting inside the 'before' box and then the model being scaled in the proportions such that after scaling it would fit into the 'after' box then you have managed to visualise what I'm trying to achieve.

I hope there is a fix for this and I look forward to hearing from anyone that can help.

Russell

Comment: It sounds like you might benefit form using a [Lattice](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/lattice.html) modifier, with an increased Resolution. (and possibly [an add-on](https://github.com/BenjaminSauder/SimpleLattice) to simplifying using one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *Lattice modifier* for this.
It works almost exactly as you described.

1. Add a *Lattice Modifier* to your Mesh.
2. Create a new Lattice through *Add > Lattice* and deform it to your needs
3. Target the new Lattice object and use the *Strength* slider to control the influence

[image]

Comment: Absolutely perfect answer.

Thank you for this. I googled a video of how to use it and within 10 minutes became an expert (well almost)